# Change language of Sign in with Apple button SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple

I have a simple sign in with apple and I want to change the language of the button to another european language, like portuguese. How can I change that?

I ve already changed my device location but the button its still on english:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoOMg.png)

```
SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn, onRequest: { request in

                                isLoggingIn = true

                                
                    request.requestedScopes = [.email]
                            }, onCompletion: { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let authResults):
                                    guard let credentials = authResults.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, let identityToken = credentials.identityToken, let identityTokenString = String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
```

Comment: Is your app fully localized for the other language? Is the device's language set to one of the localized languages that your app supports? Note that settings the device's region does not change the language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Localizable.strings set up?

If you don't know what that is or no, you need to [create a Localizable.strings for each language you want to localize the button to](https://medium.com/@eng.angloesam2010/simple-way-for-localization-in-swiftui-4134e21a50ca).

Comment: How can that be used in `SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn, ...)`

Comment: localizable strings are applied to the entire app? or just for a specific view?

Comment: @flora54 An app will only show components in the languages that your app fully supports. This includes Apple provided components. Let’s say you want to support English and German. You need to localize your app for English and German. Then only if a user’s device is set to German will everything appear in German. Otherwise everything will appear in English.